# problema con funciones en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Amigos tengo un problema con este codigo me pueden ayudar siempre me dice que contador es 0 y por ende me dice que el digito no se encuentra en el vector este es mi codigo:

```
#-*coding:utf-8-*-
''' Construir una función que reciba como parámetros un vector de 10 posiciones entera luego leer un digito y retorne la cantidad de veces que dicho dígito se encuentra en el vector'''
from ejercicio32 import rellenar_lista #Aqui importe una funcion que me llena el vector


def digito(digito,vector):

    for a in range(len(vector)):
        numero=vector[a]
        cont=0

        while numero>0:
            digito2=numero%10
            if digito2==digito:
                cont+=1
            numero=numero//10

    if cont>0:
        resultado=cont

    else:
        resultado=0

    return resultado


def main():
    try:
        elementos=10
        num=rellenar_lista(elementos)
        digito2=input("Escriba un digito: ")
        digito2=digito(digito2,num)

        if digito2>0:
            print("El digito se encuentra %d"%digito2 + " veces en el vector")

        else:
            print("El digito no se encuentra en el vector")


    except ValueError:
        print("El valor digitado debe ser numerico")

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hola! Porque nesesitas el ciclo while numero>0?, ademas solamente estas evaluando la cantidad de veces que aparece un número en un vector, cierto?

Answer (score 0):

Viendo tu código creo que te estás complicando mucho para sacar el resultado que buscas. He generado dos funciones `digito()`, una más sencilla y una un poco más compleja, pero tampoco mucho.

```
def digito(digito, vector):
    contador = 0
    for i in vector:
        if digito == i:
            contador += 1
    return contador
```

Lo que te pide el ejercicio es que devuelvas el número de coincidencias de un determinado número en un vector (lista, array..) por lo que con devolver el contador te valdría, este contador lo que hace es aumentar en 1 cada vez que `digito` es igual a uno de los elementos del vector. Por supuesto se inicializa a `0` por si no hubiese coincidencias que devuelva `0`.

También he creado esta sencilla función que a mi, personalmente, me gusta más.

```
def digito_2(digito, vector):
    contador = [i for i in vector if digito == i]
    return len(contador)
```

Aquí lo que estoy haciendo es crear una *compreshion list*, que es una manera habitual de crear listas, diccionarios, etc.. Esta lista contendrá aquellos dígitos que sean iguales a la variable `digito` y el `return` devolverá la longitud de la lista, que es igual al número de repeticiones.

**Salida sobre las funciones creadas**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te sea de ayuda, si tienes alguna duda más, escríbela en los comentarios y actualizaré mi respuesta.